# "failed to locate view layout, tried..."

Tags: node.js, express

My Node.js app is configured as such:

```
app.configure(function() {
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

  //etc.
});
```

My views folder only contains `index.ejs` and I don't want to use layouts now. However I am getting:

```
failed to locate view "layout", tried:
   - /Users/stephane/code/node/project/views/layout.ejs
```

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option to specify that we don't want to use layouts within the view:

```
app.set('view options', {
   layout: false
});
```